# Loading dependencies from nixpkgs-unstable with nix-shell

Tags: nix, nixos

I am on NixOS 16.09 and I want to use packages which are currently only in nixpkgs-unstable / nixos-unstable.

Using `nix-channel --add`, I was able to add nixpkgs-unstable to my (user) channels and use it to install the latest version of some packages with `nix-env`.

However, I understand that while `nix-env` depends on user-defined channels, `nix-shell` instead depends on the `NIX_PATH` environment variable, in my case:

```
$ echo $NIX_PATH 
nixpkgs=/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/nixpkgs:nixos-config=/etc/nixos/configuration.nix:/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels
```

So this clearly shows the problem: `nix-shell` is going to use the system-wide NixOS 16.09 channel instead of the user-defined nixpkgs-unstable channel.

Right now, I am using this workaround:

```
nix-shell -I nixpkgs=~/.nix-defexpr/channels/nixpkgs
```

It does not look very pretty to me. What would be the recommended way of doing this?

Is it to add something like:

```
export NIX_PATH="nixpkgs=~/.nix-defexpr/channels/nixpkgs:nixos-config=/etc/nixos/configuration.nix:/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels"
```

to my `.profile`? It does not look very pretty either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to a long-standing confusion with `nix-env` and `NIX_PATH`. It is explicitly stated, that `nix-env` doesn't use NIX_PATH, which makes it (I think) the only Nix tool which doesn't respect `NIX_PATH`.

So, the actual problem is with `nix-env` here, not `nix-shell`. I'll post a bunch of issues on Nix bug tracker about this:

- https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/993
- https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/1067
- https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/886

> Right now, I using this workaround:

So now you can see, this isn't a workaround. It is a good practice to always specify which exact Nixpkgs you'd like to use: your roots channel version, your channel version, upstream remote channel version, local git checkout or pinned git version.

Answer (score 2):

To complete the other answer, here is a good reference that I just found that explains `NIX_PATH` and the fact that `nix-env` does not use it: http://lethalman.blogspot.fr/2014/09/nix-pill-15-nix-search-paths.html